# Ubuntu 16. Trying to set up 3 different monitors

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I try to setup 3 different monitors on Ubuntu 16.04. What I have:

[image]

Red is build-in notebook monitor. Orange is and green are external monitors connected via Mini-DisplayPort and HDMI.

And they are works perfect. But I want change order of monitors:

[image]

And I cannot to do it with drag and drop operation! I can shift green monitor to left. But I cannot shift orange to right! How to do it?

Maybe it will help for answer:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1360x768+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02 +  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80*   59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 359mm x 287mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

And

```
$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
[sudo] пароль для mnv: 
  *-display               
       описание: 3D controller
       продукт: GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] [10DE:1391]
       производитель: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       физический ID: 0
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:01:00.0
       версия: a2
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       конфигурация: driver=nouveau latency=0
       ресурсы: IRQ:34 память:f6000000-f6ffffff память:e0000000-efffffff память:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(размер=128) память:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       описание: VGA compatible controller
       продукт: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:416]
       производитель: Intel Corporation [8086]
       физический ID: 2
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:02.0
       версия: 06
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       конфигурация: driver=i915 latency=0
       ресурсы: IRQ:35 память:f7400000-f77fffff память:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(размер=64)
```

Comment: Is the xrandr output from the situation as in the image? that seems odd, since the xrandr output shows the built in screen rightmost? Did you change it afterwards? The arrangment could be made, but I'd need to know which is which. Please leave a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run 3x1920x1200 and often have to edit ~/.config/monitors.xml to manually set their order, and X/Y pos.

*I have profiles for work and home...monitors.work.xml, monitors.home.xml